# Output is losing a character after reading input

Tags: c++

I used the below code in C++ to read characters from the user into a string, including space characters:

```
cin.ignore();
string s;
getline(cin,s);
cout<<s<<endl;
```

After taking input, the output is not the same:

```
input: gee ks for gee ks
output: ee ks for gee ks
```

Why is this?

Comment: Whatever problem you are having with your "map function" is unrelated to how you are reading the user's input, so you should ask about that map issue in a separate question, not in this question.  One question per post, please.

Answer (score 3):

`cin.ignore()` is discarding the 1st character typed by the user, and then `getline()` reads the remaining characters until a line break is reached. That is why your output is missing the `g` character from `gee`.